# Finding if the improper integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{3\arctan(x)\,dx}{ \sqrt{x^4+1}}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The directions for the problem is to find out whether the following integral converges or diverges. The integral is $$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{3\arctan(x)\,dx}{ \sqrt{x^4+1}}$$

I tried using the Direct Comparison Test with $$\frac{3}{ \sqrt{x^4+1}}$$
But I find this hard to take the integral of. Does anyone know what to do from here?

Comment: I don't understand the *hard to take the integral of* part. You do not have to compute it, just to prove it exists, which is pretty trivial by comparison with $\frac{1}{x^2}$ (which has unit integral over $[1,+\infty)$).

Comment: this integral converges

Answer (score 3):

Notice that 
$$\left\vert \frac{3\arctan x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\right\vert\le \frac{3\pi}2\frac1{x^2}$$
and the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$$
exists which allows you to conclude.